# Can Excel Dashboards update automatically?

Tags: python, excel, dashboard

I need to create a dashboard based upon an excel table and I know excel has a feature for creating dashboards. I have seen tutorials on how to do it and have done my research, but in my case, the excel table on which the dashboard would be based is updated every 2 minutes by a python script. My question is, does the dashboard display automatically if a value in the table has modified, or does it need to be reopened, reloaded, etc..?

Answer (score 1):

If the "dashboard" is in Excel and if it contains charts that refer to data in the current workbook's worksheets, then the charts will update automatically when the data is refreshed, unless the workbook calculation mode is set to "manual". By default calculation mode is set to "automatic", so changes in data will immediately reflect in charts based on that data.

If the "dashboard" lives in some other application that looks at the Excel workbook for the source data, you may need to refresh the data connections in the dashboard application after the Excel source data has been refreshed.